# eBay errorId 1100: "Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request"

Tags: html, api, curl, oauth

I've requested OAuth token with scopes:

- `https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account.readonly` and
- `https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account`

I generate a new OAuth Application Token **for production** and attempt to run [getPrivileges](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/account/resources/privilege/methods/getPrivileges) as such:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer myOAuthToken" https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account`

Output is error message:

```
{"errors":[{
"errorId":1100,
"domain":"ACCESS",
"category":"REQUEST",
"message":"Access denied",
"longMessage":"Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request."
}]}
```

...but I expect a status return "200 OK". I know this `curl` call works when doing something like
`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer myOAuthToken" https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=myQuery`
so the only thing I can think of is the scopes, but unless I'm mistaken the scopes are appropriate for the getPrivileges call. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found in [this post](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/28275/insufficient-permissions-to-fulfill-the-request-er.html) there is a special clause that this call requires a token that was specifically generated through the authorization code grant flow. Instead of generating an OAuth straight from my User Tokens page, I walked through the grant flow and generated a token and it works.